# JavaScript: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, dom-events

I am getting the error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

With this javascript:

```
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-coll');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    nav[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log('haha');
        }
    }, false);
};
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: I just love how the question is regarded as "too localized" and it has been seen over 145,000 times.

Comment: This is an important question. I just helped me. It should not be close.

Comment: For me, I had a function call where I put the function's inputs on the next line. Automatic semicolon injection then caused issues (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18221979/6068036).

Answer (score 51):

You have an extra closing `}` in your function.

```
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-coll');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    nav[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log('haha');
        }        // <== remove this brace
    }, false);
};
```

You really should be using something like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) or [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to help find these things. These tools integrate with many editors and IDEs, or you can just paste a code fragment into the above web sites and ask for an analysis.

Comment: For me it was a ";" after my function close } but your answer helped find it. Installed JSlint and looked for errors

Answer (score 16):

You got an extra `}` to many as seen below:

```
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-coll');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    nav[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log('haha');
        } // <-- REMOVE THIS :)
    }, false);
};
```

A very good tool for those things is [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/). I have created a fiddle with your invalid code and when clicking the `TidyUp` button it formats your code which makes it clearer if there are any possible mistakes with missing braces.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6kwwz/) - Your code in a fiddle, have a play :)

---

Comment: wow...i'm sorry it was a really stupid mistake, i use SublimeText 2 but i just couldn't see it, i think i'm going to sleep...Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6):

just posting in case anyone else has the same error...

I was using 'await' outside of an 'async' function and for whatever reason that results in a 'missing ) after argument list' error.

The solution was to make the function asynchronous

```
function functionName(args) {}
```

becomes

```
async function functionName(args) {}
```

Comment: I'm doing the same exact thing and getting the same exact error, except I *did* use the `async` keyword (in fact whether I use it or not does not change a thing)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Josh McGee, I was trying to use `await` in the global scope, which, since it isn't an `async` function, will throw an error. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51525234/9063935) for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This error maybe is the version of your Android (especially if you are using Web Views), try to change your code like an old version of the JavaScript Engine, like:

```
   .then(function(canvas){
            //canvas object can gained here
   });
```

Comment: Nope, pretty sure the highly voted answers got it right with the extra closing brace `}`

Comment: The point here is that if you try to use lambda .then(canvas => { //code canvas obj });

the compiler throws this error, altrought it not have any relation with "missing arguments" (if you're using old Android version, where Chrome use a old version of JavaScript engine). Probably in the epoch the compiler was not optimized/fixed to show correct error messages

;

Comment: True but it's not the problem in the question.

Comment: Yes, although it was with this problem how I got here. Await for Google indexing.

Comment: And the error is a fairly generic syntax error

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you are missing a (tick) '

**Failed:**

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSideMethod))
            {
                return "function(e){" + clientSideMethod + " OnOptionChangedDxGrid(e," + hasConditionalFormatting.ToString().ToLower() + "','" + "false".ToString().ToLower() + "', '" + string.Empty + "'); }";
            }
            else
            {
                return "function(e){ OnOptionChangedDxGrid(e," + hasConditionalFormatting.ToString().ToLower() + "','" + "false".ToString().ToLower() + "', '" + string.Empty + "'); }";
            }
```

**Worked:**

```
        public static string GetOnOptionChangedMethodCall(string clientSideMethod, bool hasConditionalFormatting)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSideMethod))
            {
                return "function(e){" + clientSideMethod + " OnOptionChangedDxGrid(e,'" + hasConditionalFormatting.ToString().ToLower() + "','" + "false".ToString().ToLower() + "', '" + string.Empty + "'); }";
            }
            else
            {
                return "function(e){ OnOptionChangedDxGrid(e,'" + hasConditionalFormatting.ToString().ToLower() + "','" + "false".ToString().ToLower() + "', '" + string.Empty + "'); }";
            }
        }
```

Notice there is a missing (tick) ` before the first double quote: `(e," + hasConditionalFormatting.ToString()`

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error and I figured with the increased use of ES6 and string interpolation, that more and more people would start making the same mistake I did with [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

Initially, I logged a statement like so:

```
console.log(`Metadata: ${data}`);
```

But then changed it and forgot to remove the `${}`:

```
console.log('Metadata: ' + JSON.stringify(${data}));
```