# Javascript function fails to return object when there is a line-break between the return statement and the object?

Tags: javascript

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzdQP/)

The full code:

```
function foo1(){
    return {msg: "hello1"};
}
function foo2(){
    return
    {msg: "hello2"};
}

// output = "foo1 =  {"msg":"hello1"}"
console.log('foo1 = ' , JSON.stringify(foo1())); 

//output = " foo2 =  undefined "
console.log('foo2 = ' , JSON.stringify(foo2()));
```

The difference between the two is that in foo2, the `{msg: 'hello'}` is in its own new line. I was expecting the parser to ignore whitespaces?

Comment: not with a return statement I do believe, I remember reading it somewhere that this is one of the rare cases in JS that the whitespace does matter. Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528557/a-return-statement-in-javascript-does-not-work-properly-if-the-return-value-is

Comment: Check this link: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/

Comment: Certain whitespace. Any number of normal ASCII spaces are fine, whereas not a single LF/CR is permitted. Seems arbitrary, but I'm going to assume there's a logical explanation for why I lost an hour on this matter last night. The linter's error message could have been more exact/helpful....

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**tl;dr** The line break is causing the 'undefined' in the second function. JavaScript doesn't require semicolons in a lot of cases and just assumes them in certain contexts ([Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)).

---

In certain cases, to avoid this ASI problem and for aesthetic reasons, I use the so-called [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping). For example, with the [hoquet](https://github.com/tjb1982/hoquet) templating DSL (it compiles Arrays as s-expressions into HTML), I like to group the Arrays so that they clearly show the HTML structure:

```
return (
  ["ul"
  , ["li"
    , ["span", {class: "name"}, this.name]
    , ["span", {id: "x"}, "x"]
    ]
  ]
);
```

which seems somewhat clearer, or more consistent to me than

```
return [
  "ul",
  [
    "li",
    ["span", {class: "name"}, this.name],
    ["span", {id: "x"}, "x"]
  ]
];
```

and they end up with the same number of lines. But it's a matter of aesthetics, really.

---

The grouping operator just evaluates whatever expression is inside of it. You see this commonly with [Immediately Invoked Function Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression#Usage), where you need to turn what would normally be a function *declaration* into an *expression*, which can then be immediately invoked (hence, the name). However, a perhaps lesser known feature of the grouping operator is that it can also take a comma-delimited list of expressions, e.g.

```
function() {
  return (
    doSideEffects(),
    console.log("this is the second side effect"),
    1 + 1
  );
}
```

In this case it evaluates each of these expressions and returns only the last one (1 + 1).

Comment: As a good rule... always keep the return statement on one line in JavaScript.

Comment: To make matters worse, there are parsing differences between how Chrome/ Firefox interpret end-of-line and how IE interprets its.

Comment: Related: [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Comment: @JonB: There are? Could you provide some examples?

Comment: ASI should be abolished. It has no reason to exist except legacy code. `return \n (exp);` should work the same as `var foo = \n (exp);`

Comment: +1 if for no other reason than I finally found this after a zillion hits about inserting `\n` into a "returned string."  Goodness, such a relief, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Accepted Answer seems to be correct.

However I found this variant of a return line with line break at a function arg opening bracket DOES work:

```
myFunction(){
  return myOtherFucntion(
           myArg);
}
```

And this other variant with line break before '.' dot operator ALSO works:

```
myFunction(){
  return myObject
           .myObjectFunction();
}
```

(The style/readability of my examples are obviously a bit odd, but try to just pay attention to the conclusions they make, and exercise your own style as you find appropriate).