# JavaScript returning object not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var doBlah = function(param0) {

  return {
    objectMember: function( param1 )
    {
        var a  = param1;
    }
  }
}
```

Which works fine but when I do a different indentation as:

```
var doBlah = function(param0) {

  return
  {
    objectMember: function( param1 )
    {
        var a  = param1;
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Why is this? Seems to be behaving similar to python.
Any references to official docs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Javascript attempts to insert missing semicolons for you, so `return` followed by a newline is often "corrected" to `return;`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221963/javascript-function-fails-to-return-object-when-there-is-a-line-break-between-th).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in js the new line can be considered as end of an statement so your code will look like

```
var doBlah = function(param0) {

  return ;//this is ended here
  { //here you have block definition starting
    objectMember: function( param1 )//now you have an invalid syntax here
    {
        var a  = param1;
    }
  }
}
```

So

```
var doBlah = function(param0) {

  return {
    objectMember: function( param1 )
    {
        var a  = param1;
    }
  }
}
```

- [Automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)
- [return - Automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)