# Angular provider showing error

Tags: angularjs, provider

In my angular code, in provider showing some error unexpected token

```
var app= angular.module('myapp',[]);


app.provider('date',function() {
    return {
        $get:function()
        {
            return
            {
                    showDate:function()
                    {
                        return 4;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

);
```

Comment: Seeing the first return statement inside $get makes me wince. See this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221963/javascript-function-fails-to-return-object-when-there-is-a-line-break-between-th).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close your first function with a '}'

```
var app= angular.module('myapp',[]);


app.provider('date',function() {
    return {
        $get:function()
        {
            return
            {
                showDate:function()
                {
                    return 4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will automatically insert a semicolon after your second `return` statement. Try

```
return {
   showDate:function()
   {
        return 4;
   }
}
```

Working JSFiddle (Combined with JulCh's answer): https://jsfiddle.net/qs6ufoo3/

Comment: showing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( --- near  $get:function()  in the provider.

Comment: I updated my answer with mine and JulCh's suggestions combined in a JSFiddle.

Comment: i have tried with jsfiddle. but not getting resulet

Comment: The provided Fiddle works and does not give any errors. Maybe there is a problem with how you are using the code snippet.

Comment: No getting result. just showing {{message}}. but it should display what i am returning here like 4. i have also tried in plunker(plnkr.co/)

Comment: I can't help you more without seeing more of your code. There is no {{message}} in your question.