# mapStateToProps() returning undefined, when integrating Redux with ReactNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am currently dealing with two screens: Login and EmployeeList and didn't set initialRouteName.

I have combined two reducers: NavReducer and AuthReducer. I am receiving state.auth in LoginForm and state.nav in RouterWithNavigationState like so:

```
class RouterWithNavigationState extends Component{
    ...
    <Router navigation = {addNavigationHelpers({
                    dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                    state: this.props.navigation
                })} />
    ...
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state =>
    {
        console.log (state.nav)
        return 
        {
           navigation: state.nav
        } 
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RouterWithNavigationState)
```

However I get an error: 
(1) `mapStateToProps() in Connect(RouterWithNavigationState) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.` 
(2) `addNavigationHelpers is not a function` 
The log statement prints the initial state I defined in NavReducer.js like so: `{index: 0, routes: Array(1)}`

package.json: 
`"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.3",
    "react-navigation": "^2.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  }`

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function fails to return object when there is a line-break between the return statement and the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221963/javascript-function-fails-to-return-object-when-there-is-a-line-break-between-th)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi