# Return multiple values in switch case using react.js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am using a switch case to render text based on the case value. In addition to the text, I also want to add an icon. So for a particular case, there would be an icon and next to it there would be an appropriate text.

[image]

To implement that, I am adding icon and text in return statement of case condition.

```
     case 'DENIED':
       return <Square /> + intl.formatMessage(messages.processDenied);
     case 'CANCELLED':
       return <CloseIcon color='red' /> + intl.formatMessage(messages.processCancelled);
     case 'INCOMPLETE':
       return <HourglassIcon /> + intl.formatMessage(messages.processIncomplete);
     default:
        return intl.formatMessage(messages.processApproved);
}
```

When I use the above logic, I get

[image]

Instead of displaying icon, it displays [object,object]. Can I not use '+' sign to concatenate two elements ? If so, how do I return both the elements in a single return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I not use '+' sign to concatenate two elements ?

No, that performs string concatenation. A React element is an object, not a string. The default string representation of an object is `[object Object]` which is why you get that output.

> If so, how do I return both the elements in a single return?

Either use a **[fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)** or put both elements inside another one:

```
// fragment
return <><Square /> {intl.formatMessage(messages.processDenied)}</>;

// children of another element
return <span><Square /> {intl.formatMessage(messages.processDenied)}</span>;
```

Comment: I believe you can also wrap the line with parenthesis like so: return (<HourglassIcon /> {intl.formatMessage(messages.processIncomplete)});

Comment: @Alex: No, that's invalid JavaScript.

Comment: How so? The return statement in the render function is wrapped with parenthesis in React and if the switch block is in the Render, it can only return one JSX element.

Comment: Yes I tried wrapping the line in () but it doesn't work.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it can only return one parent element. You'll need to wrap it with a span, div, or fragment. My bad.

Comment: Fragment option didn't work either. But adding a parent element works fine.

Comment: @alex: First of all, `{intl.formatMessage(messages.processIncomplete)}` is invalid *JavaScript*. `{...}` denotes an object literal in your example and this invalid syntax for an object literal. Even if you omit the `{...}`, the code would become `return (React.createElement(...) intl.formatMessage(...))`. You cannot just put two function calls after each other in a single expression.

Comment: @alex: *"The return statement in the render function is wrapped with parenthesis in React"* That's usually done to prevent automatic semicolon insertion when the value to return is written on the next line after `return`. That is not specific to React. I.e. `return 42;`  works fine, but `return <linebreak> 42;` will not. `return ( <linebreak> 42 );` will work. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/18221963/218196 .

Comment: @user2128: yeah, whether fragments work or not really depends on how the return value of the function is used. If this is returning from a `render` function it should work though.