# Getting "Undefined" value for Variable even though i have defined variable

Tags: javascript

HI I have defined variable called "const VA" but in output it is coming  undefine cause  of that i am not able to see values inside it
below is my code.

```
function createAddress(streetA, cityA, zipcodeA) {
  return
  {
    streetA, cityA, zipcodeA;
  }
}
const VA = createAddress("405", "newyork", "123456");
console.log(VA);
```

Output is `undefined`

Comment: You can't have a linebreak after a return statement, just one of those things.   Move your curly bracket onto the same line (ie  `return {` )

Comment: @BrianPatterson, you should probably have that as an answer.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Sure, why not.  :)

Comment: `streetA, cityA, zipcodeA` unreachable code.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18221963/8376184

Comment: @JohnLord Once you reach 2000 reputation, you can edit any post and approve or reject suggestions...

Comment: @BrianPatterson Thanks ,It worked .I am new to JS  so these  small small issues  iam facing  thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to automatic semi-colon insertion, if you put a line-break after a return statement, javascript will put a semi-colon after it and nothing will be returned.   You simply need to move the curly bracket up onto the same line to prevent this.

Reference: [ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)

```
function createAddress(streetA,cityA,zipcodeA)
      {
          return {
                streetA,
                cityA,
                zipcodeA  
             };
      };


const VA = createAddress ('405','newyork','123456');    
console.log(VA);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a line break for the brackets after the `return`. 
Use this instead:

```
return {
    value,
    value2,
    value3
}
```