# Javascript opening curly brace style change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have javescript code like this. This code is for Vue. I understand that put the opening curly brace at the line end of a statement is a common practice in JS world.

```
<script>
export default
{
  name: 'newUser',
  data () {
    return {
      message: 'Hello World'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

There is nothing wrong with this. However, just as a personal preference I found this style very annoying. I prefer following style:

```
<script>
export default
{
  name: 'newUser',
  data () 
  {
    return 
    {
      message: 'Hello World'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

However, if I change the style, Vue complains that "Opening curly brace does not appear on the same line as controlling statement". So my question here is that, is the first style mandated by javascript or just the Vue? Is there a way to bypass it and let me use the style I like? I guess not only Vue, but other JS frontend frameworks (e.g. React) also dislike the second style.

Comment: Your `return` does different things in the two pieces of code you've shown. [Javascript function fails to return object when there is a line-break between the return statement and the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18221963) | [Why doesn't a Javascript return statement work when the return value is on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8528557) | [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283)

Comment: If anything, likely some linter set up with default rules is complaining about this, not "Vue".

Comment: Do you have a clue where I can find out this mysterious linter and it's configuration so that I can disable it?

Comment: How did you set up your project? Vue CLI? Then start here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config

Comment: What you are doing in the second snippet of code is contrary to JavaScript. In JavaScript, whatever you are returning must be on the same line with with the `return` statement. Even if you have to write it that way, move the opening brace of the object you want to return to the same line as the `return` statement

Comment: I am new to JS. So you are saying JS actually forces the opening brace to be at the same line as return?

Comment: Yes. Also: if you're new to a language, try to adapt to its common style, instead of forcing a style from some other language you're used to on it. That's a lot easier in the long run.

Answer (score -2):

#### Yes, the first style is mandated by JavaScript.

Your code will not run as expected.
JavaScript has [Automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion)

Look at this example: [Vue SFC Playgorund](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{func1 == undefined ? 'undefined' : func1.string}}
  </div>
    <div>
    {{func2 == undefined ? 'undefined' : func2.string}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  computed: {
    func1() {
      return {
        string: "hello"
      }
    },
    func2() {
      return
      {
        string: "hello"
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```