# No output React Js for web

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, output

My react application is giving no output, there are no errors.
First it worked fine, now the same thing is not working.

I've tried React.render and ReactDOM.render
I've tried with and without render()

App.js

````
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function Greeting()
{
  
    return
    (
      <h1>helllo</h1>
    );
  
}



ReactDOM.render
(
  <Greeting/>,document.getElementById('root')
);

--------------------------**Index.css**----------------------------------

    ```body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
        'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
        sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    
    code {
      font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
        monospace;
    }
````

Comment: Keep the bracket after the return statement on the same line. Else the JS compiler considers the `return` and the block in the brackets to be two different statements. So it takes `return;` as the output of the `Greeting` function

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `return` statement(`line-break issue`), if you return value in `next line`, it will be consider as `undefined`. that's why you can't see anything on dom. Read [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221963/javascript-function-fails-to-return-object-when-there-is-a-line-break-between-th) for more understanding

```
return
    (
      <h1>helllo</h1>
    );
```

change to

```
 return (
   <h1>helllo</h1>
 );
```

Also format your code little bit.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting/>,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, in a functional component you only need to return the JSX/JS, class based component need render [Difference b/w class and functional component](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-functional-components-and-class-components-in-react/#:%7E:text=A%20functional%20component%20is%20just,which%20returns%20a%20React%20element.)

The correct working code can be found below.

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";

function Greeting() {
  return <h1>helllo</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Greeting />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: tried. stilll no output @pratyush

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot with browser console logs.