# using await on global scope without async keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to do something like this on **global scope** in nodejs REPL. As per my understanding both the following statements are valid. [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
let x = await Promise.resolve(2);
let y = await 2;
```

However, both these statements are throwing an error.

Can somebody explain why?
my node version is v8.9.4

Comment: Why?  Because that's how `async/await` was designed.  If you want to go into why it's designed that way, it is complicated, but it has to do with the single-threaded event driven nature of Javascript and how much change they could absorb in one major revision of the engine.  And, with modules assuming to be loading synchronously, top level `await` causes all sorts of problems with that assumption.  Put your own `async` wrapper around things you want to use `await` with.

Comment: You don't or you wait for [top-level async](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221) to cause a whole slew of issues.

Comment: You could write your own REPL that wraps all code entered in an AIiFE.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Update

When using **Node**, the file currently must have an `.mjs` extension to work.

Top level `awaits` can be used in browser modules. When used the script tag must include the `type` attribute which must be set to `module`:

```html
<script src="/script.js" type="module"></script>
```

```js
const start = Date.now()

console.log('Pre call.')
await delayedCall()
console.log('Duration:', Date.now() - start)

function delayedCall() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000))
}
```

- [Working Node Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-bnhn4q?file=index.mjs) -- Run `node ./index.mjs` in the terminal.
- [Working Browser Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-rwvgfh)
- [Supported Versions](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_await_top_level)

### Old Answer

`await` can only be used within a function that is labeled `async`, so there are two ways you can approach this.

**Note:**
There is a proposal in place that may eventually allow the usage of [Top level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) calls.

The first way is to create a self invoked function like this:

```js
(async function() {
  let x = await Promise.resolve(2)
  let y = await 2
  
  console.log(x, y)
})()
```

Or the second way is to use `.then()`

```js
Promise.resolve(2).then(async data => {
  let x = data
  let y = await 2

  console.log(x, y)
})
```

Comment: Your second code block is pretty messed up.  `await` is in the wrong place, `=>` must not have a space between them.  `await 2` makes no sense.

Comment: Well, IMO good answers don't repeat bad code, they correct it and explain why.

Comment: Also, it's bad to assign to `x` and `y` in a higher scope.  That is usually a sign that someone wants to try to use those variables in a higher scope and that usually won't work because the timing of when they are set.  If I were you, I'd just remove your second code example.  It's not how one should do things.

Comment: I understand you have to use await in an async function. I don't understand why they can't just make the global context act as if it is executing in an async function. Would save people having to write ugly boiler plate wrappers like this.

Comment: Top-level await is currently available in node.js v13.3+ behind the `--harmony-top-level-await` flag, but it can only be used in modules (files with `*.mjs` extension or with `*.js` accompanied with package.json setting `"type": "module"`), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585793/top-level-await-doesnt-work-in-the-latest-node-js/59585976#59585976) for sources

Answer (score 10):

As of version 13.3, Node.js support [Top-level await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await).

Top-level `await` means you can now use `await` operator outside an `async` function. So both examples are correct:

```
(async function() {

  await Promise.resolve(console.log('Hello await!'));

}());

// or

await Promise.resolve(console.log('Hello await!'));
```

**Note**: Top-level await only works at the top level of modules. There is no support for classic scripts or non-async functions.

**Just keep in mind**, that the `await` operator is used to wait for a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). It does NOT matter if you are using an `await` operator with a value other than a Promise. For example, the `name` variable in the displayName()` function:

```
async function displayName() {

  const name = await 'unclexo';

  console.log(name);
}

displayName(); // outputs 'unclexo'
```

As the value of the `name` variable is not a Promise, it converts the value to a resolved Promise, and waits for it. It happens under the hood.

**The old behavior**

[MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) says

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. **It can only be used
> inside an async function.**

Comment: outdated answer

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. Updated the answer. Let me know if it is Ok.

Comment: "Top-level await means you can now use await operator outside an async function. So both examples are correct" That is not correct. You can use the await keyword on its own (outside of an async function) at the top level **of a module**. The last sentence is actually a quote from the link you provided.

Answer (score 8):

This proposal is currently in stage 3 of the TC39 process. [LINK](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)

You can use this feature in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox as of now. You can use top level await without async in console.

[image: Top level await in console]

https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/1080365576218759168

Answer (score 4):

since node 10, you can run node process with --experimental-repl-await to allow top level await
https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_await_keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getTen() {
  return 10;
}

(async () => {
  let ten = await getTen();
  console.log(ten);
})();
```

Source: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/5-javascript-interview-questions-to-identify-outstanding-developers-859a71c3d7f

Answer (score 0):

[Top-level-await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) is supported in Node.js version 13.3 or above

Example:

```
await Promise.resolve(console.log('')); // →
```

(Though the question is about REPL, a note on running as script file. Set `{"type": "module"}` *package.json* or use the file name extension *.mjs*)

Answer (score -2):

You could wrap all the code in the global scope in an async function.

For example:

```
// ...global imports...

new Promise (async () => {

  // ...all code in the global scope...

}).then()
```

Comment: gregn3, The purpose of the question was not to use promise chaining using ```.then()``` or ```.catch()```

Comment: @nmxl You didn't mention this in your question though.

Comment: At least it's not zero :)