# Top-level await doesn't work in the latest Node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await

Is top-level `await` still not supported in Node.js (Jan 2020, Node.js 13.5.0)?

I've tried some tutorials, like [this one](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-await-top-level/), but still no luck, always getting the same error:

```
D:\NodeJS>node --experimental-modules test.js
(node:17724) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///D:/NodeJS/test.js:9
await test();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

The entire file content:

```js
function test() {
}

await test();
```

I have tried using `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, and renaming file into `test.mjs`, but still the same error, even with the latest Node.js 13.5.0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: top-level await is still a stage 3 proposal, what makes you think it's an experimental feature in node?

Comment: The article you refer to only talks about ES modules, not top level await

Comment: that article describes enabling ES modules, which have been in the spec for a while, not top-level await which is still a proposal

Comment: @Klaycon As I explained, I did try renaming the file to `*.mjs`, and setting `type` to `module`, but none worked. Those things were supposed to turn the script into ES module.

Comment: Then why is your question about top level await?? I think you are mixing up 2 separate topics.

Comment: the script *is* an ES module. ES modules don't support top-level await yet, because adding top-level await to ES modules is still a stage 3 proposal and has not been implemented.

Comment: Guys, apologies, I just realized I clicked the ES module link and was providing the wrong link. [Here's the link I intended to provide](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-await-top-level/). Updated the question also.

Comment: @vitaly-t looking into it further, there aren't many resources, but i was able to find a flag that should work, please see my answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per [this issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=9344) and [this blog post](https://2ality.com/2019/12/top-level-await.html#implementations), top-level await is available in Node v13.3+ behind the flag `--harmony-top-level-await`. The module flag you're enabling is only for ESM modules and not for top level await.

Comment: That works, almost. [So that article is incorrect then](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-await-top-level/)? Because it doesn't work, unless I use `mjs` file extension, or set `"type": "module"` inside `package.json`.

Comment: @vitaly-t The article as well as the spec do state that top-level await will only work in ESM modules and never in commonjs modules, so you'll have to use the `mjs` extension or `"type": "module"` regardless. The article should mention that the feature is only in V8 behind that flag, but doesn't. It simply says it will "take some time" before it's available in node.

Comment: Also, when replacing that flag with just `--harmony`, nothing works then.

Comment: Ah, my mistake then. I read elsewhere that `--harmony` enables all harmony flags. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I'm using Node v14.7.0 and I cannot find any `--harmony` flag in `node --help` but there is a `--experimental-repl-await` flag that does the trick for me.

Comment: exec `node --v8-options | grep await` and you can see `--harmony-top-level-await`

Answer (score 4):

`node --experimental-repl-await`
works for the Node REPL

**edit**: the Node 16  REPL accepts top level await by default, you don't need the experimental flag anymore

Comment: Additionally, if you always want to have it enabled without explicitly passing the flag, you can `export NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-repl-await'` in your `.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

I dont know why, but to get the --harmony features like you need to use --eval (-e) or --print (-p) instead of just launching node like 
`node -e "import('./test.mjs')" --experimental-modules --input-type=module --harmony-top-level-await`

file-content:

```
console.log(await Promise.resolve("test"));
```

console:

```
node -e "import('./test.mjs')" --experimental-modules --input-type=module --harmony-top-level-await
(node:9096) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
test
```

Comment: As of `node 14.8.0` you now only need `--input-type=module`; the other two are enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

**When using `node -e`:**

Note that while top-level `await` is unflagged in node 14.8.0, when doing `node -e` (`node --eval`), the input type defaults to CJS, and top-level `await` is allowed only in ESM mode.

To tell that the input is ESM, you need a flag:

```
node --input-type=module -e 'console.log(await Promise.resolve(42))'
> 42
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could wrap your top level code into function mark it as `async` but don't wait for it's result. And only wait for the result of async action you need to wait.

That way you will have no warning, not work in 100% of situations, because top level code can be in multiple files etc. But for the majority hope could help, w/o need to change node flags, as it's not always easy (for example when you don't run any node commands yourself and need to extract some node/webpack configs)

```
setupApp()

async function setupApp () {
   await action1()
   action2()
}
```