# Nodejs / Typescript | Wrapping main code in an async IIFE for top level await

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous

I am using node 16/17 and typescript with ts-node. I want to use top-level await for a call to my database before creating my Koa app. I can't use top-level await with typescript though. I don't think this has been resolved yet, but I can wrap my main code in an async self-executing function and this works. Are there any drawbacks to this, or is there a better preferred way of doing this??

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import { connectToDatabase } from './services/database.service';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

(async function main() {
  dotenv.config();

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  await connectToDatabase();

  const app = new Koa();

  app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    const start = Date.now();
    await next();
    const ms = Date.now() - start;
    console.log(`${ctx.method} ${ctx.url} - ${ms}ms`);
  });

  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`));
})();
```

The issue stems from the `await connectToDatabase();` call, I can't top-level `await` this in typescript with nodejs. There are a bunch of weird issues, and the package-json.tson typescript file and package.json nodejs file conflict with each other...

Comment: I've not found any better way to do it.

Comment: Oh okay :) is there any performance drawbacks to this? Or nah

Comment: It won’t make a blind bit of difference to the performance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59585976/2736817