# Is there any way to export promise's result in es module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise, es6-module-loader

As `await` can only be used inside an **async function**, the code below does not work.

```
const config_path = 'https://test.cdn.com/conf.' + location.hash.include('DEV')?'development.ts':'production.ts'
const promise = import(config_path)

export default config = await promise
```

So is there any way to export promise's result in es/ts module?

Comment: Try `export default config = require(config_path)`

Comment: you cannot do so. if some method touches something async, it needs to be async. async is contagious.

Comment: @JeremyThille `require` can only be used for **node module**, not for  **cdn module**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deno` can support `top-level await`:

```
 await Promise.resolve(console.log(''));
 const strings = await import(`/i18n/${navigator.language}`);
```

And this feature for v8/chrome is in developing: https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await.

Answer (score -1):

from the [docs,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

"The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. **It can only be used inside an async function.**"

If you intend to use async await on global scope, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525234/using-await-on-global-scope-without-async-keyword/59699830#59699830) for workarounds.