# Adaptation to previous question, ReferenceError: object is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

The previous question was marked as a duplicate, with the link leading me here: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

I still couldn't find a solution, but I guess i will need AJAX to return this object, because my functions/GET Request hasn't completed, which leads me to a new question. How can I adapt this to return asynchronously. I understand the concepet of Promises and async/await, but I'm unsure how I can implement this here so I can access the object globally.

[Original Question]

Returning object from the below function, but I'm receiving this error `ReferenceError: object is not defined`. I would like to access this globally, but can't seem to access the object because of scope. Is there something that I'm missing?

When setting a global variable, this doesn't seem to update.

For example setting `var globalObject = {};` outside and using `globalObject = object` inside the object doesn't seem to change the variable `{}`

```
function getTicket (ticketID) {

  var urlID = contentID;


  var request = require("request");

  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://www.mywebsite.com/api/${urlID}/body.json`,
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', authorization: 'Basic PASSWORD=='}
  };

  request(options, function (response, body) {


    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
    var objContent = JSON.parse(obj.body);

    var object = {
      id: urlID,
      url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/api/' + urlID,
      value: objContent
    };

    console.log(object.id);
    console.log(object.url);
    console.log(objContent.body[0].body);



  });
return object;
}

getTicket(380289);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your function to return a promise and then use await when calling it:

```
function getTicket(ticketID) {
  var urlID = contentID;

  var request = require('request');

  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://www.mywebsite.com/api/${urlID}/body.json`,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json', authorization: 'Basic PASSWORD==' }
  };

  return Promise(resolve => {
    request(options, function(response, body) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
      var objContent = JSON.parse(obj.body);

      var object = {
        id: urlID,
        url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/api/' + urlID,
        value: objContent
      };

      console.log(object.id);
      console.log(object.url);
      console.log(objContent.body[0].body);
      resolve(object);
    });
  });
}

await getTicket(380289);
```

Note that your call will need to happen in an async scope. If you are in the global scope, you can use:

```
(async function() {
  await getTicket(380289);
})();
```

See [using await on global scope without async keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525234/using-await-on-global-scope-without-async-keyword) for more details