# e.preventDefault() isn't working in an es6 arrow function loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I can't get prevent default to work in an arrow function.

[addEventListener on a querySelectorAll() with classList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643302/addeventlistener-on-a-queryselectorall-with-classlist)

I wanna do it the es6 way.

```js
var clickers = document.querySelectorAll('.clicker');

clickers.forEach(clicker => 
  clicker.addEventListener("click", (e) => 
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("i clicked")
  )
);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="clicker">test</a>
<a href="#" class="clicker">test</a>
```

I'm getting this error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

[JavaScript: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558482/javascript-syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list)

This isn't es6 so this answer doesn't suffice

What I find is when you delete prevent default it goes away

```js
var clickers = document.querySelectorAll('.clicker');

clickers.forEach(clicker => 
  clicker.addEventListener("click", (e) => 
    console.log("i clicked")
  )
);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="clicker">test</a>
<a href="#" class="clicker">test</a>
```

But the the behavior is it goes to top of page when you click, or rather doesn't prevent default

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_parenthesis_after_argument_list

I checked the resource above but wasn't helpful in the specific context.

How do you fix this error?  How do you prevent default in an es6 arrow function loop?

Comment: Two statements in a function, you need `(e) => { ....; .....; }`

Comment: yikes lol that would indeed be it

Comment: explains it in the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the curly braces after the arrow in the arrow function. For a multiline arrow function curly braces are required for the block.

```js
var clickers = document.querySelectorAll('.clicker');

clickers.forEach(clicker => 
  clicker.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("i clicked")
  })
);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="clicker">test</a>
<a href="#" class="clicker">test</a>
```

Comment: *"For a multiline arrow function ..."* It's not about the number of lines but the kind of syntax that is used inside the function body. The body can either be a single expression (that can be written over as many lines as desired) or a "block" (it's not really a block but it looks like one), with any number of statements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `{}` for more than one statements.

Note that the second parameter is callback **function** that can be passed in a different way. The base form is:
`clicker.addEventListener("click", function (e) { })`

But you can use lambda expression too, in modern browsers.

```js
var clickers = document.querySelectorAll('.clicker');

clickers.forEach(clicker => 
  clicker.addEventListener("click", (e) => 
  {  e.preventDefault();
    console.log("i clicked");
  })
);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="clicker">test</a>
<a href="#" class="clicker">test</a>
```

Comment: *"You need to {} for more than one statements."* That's also not quite right. You need `{}` for any number of statements (no statement, one statement or multiple statements). You can only omit the `{}` if the body is an *expression*. E.g. `() => if (true) { return 42; }` is not valid syntax even though there is only one statement.