# I am getting an ejs error saying - Could not find matching close tag for "<%"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have checked the internet about potential causes like nested tags. There were before but I have removed them. Some place users have actually forgotten to close the tag, but I checked manually each tag but and every opening tag has a closing tag.

There are some if-else statements and one loop. I checked the syntaxes for using loops and if-else statements and made the syntaxes as saw on the internet.

Still, I am getting this issue.
Here is my Code.

```
      <header>
        <div class="logoPlant">
          <img
            src=""
            width="160"
          />
          <%=Plant%>
        </div>
        <h3>
          <% if (GatePassType === "RGP") { %> RETURNABLE GATE PASS <% } else {
          %> NON RETURNABLE GATE PASS <% } %>
        </h3>
      </header>
      <div class="data">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="line">
            <p>Gate Pass No</p>
            :
            <p><%=GatePassNo%></p>
          </div>
          <div class="line">
            <p>Issued By</p>
            :
            <p><%=DepartmentName%></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <div class="line">
            <p>Gate Pass Date</p>
            :
            <p><%=GatePassDate%></p>
          </div>
          <div class="line">
            <p>Issued To</p>
            :
            <p><%=PartyName%></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Unit</th>
          <th>Out</th>
          <% if (GatePassType === "RGP") { %>
          <th>Exp Ret. Date</th>
          <% } %>
          <th>Purpose</th>
        </tr>
        <% for(let i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) { %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= Items[i].ItemCode Items[i].ItemName %></td>
          <td><%= Items[i].Unit %></td>
          <td><%= Items[i].Quantity%></td>
          <% if (GatePassType === "RGP") { %>
          <td><%=Items[i].ReturnDate%></td>
          <% } %
          <td><%= Items[i].Remarks %></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
      </table>
      <footer>
        <p>
          N.B.: Carrier to be produce his copy at security office while
          returning the material to the factory.
        </p>
        <div class="two">
          <p><%=InitiatorEName%></p>
          <p><b>Initiated By</b></p>
          <br />
          <p><%=ApproverEName%></p>
          <p><b>Authorized By</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
          <p><%=CarrierString%></p>
          <p><b>Carrier Name</b></p>
          <br />
          <p><%=MainGateEname%></p>
          <p><b>Security By</b></p>
        </div>
      </footer>
```

Comment: so - it's a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it would be easiest to post a screen shot.
You are missing closing tag ->
[image]

Comment: Now getting this error -  missing ) after argument list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558482/javascript-syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list I think that this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It didn't work.

Comment: https://www.jslint.com/ I've entered your code here, take a look at it. Hope you will find your solution. To be honest, I'm triggered because I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `>` in this part:

```
<% if (GatePassType === "RGP") { %>
    <td><%=Items[i].ReturnDate%></td>
<% } % <- HERE
```

Comment: Now getting this error -  missing ) after argument list